# Add HTTPS Certificate to Kotlin

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

i try to add a Certificate to my Ktor project. But nothing is working. I tried this one

https://ktor.io/docs/ssl.html

But it doesnt work. There is always a error mesaage saying SSL handshake failed or something like this. Why?

I tried this one https://ktor.io/docs/ssl.html but only handshake failed with certificate